# Angular - Pass an enumeration in a radio group

Tags: angular

**Tools**

Using Jhipster v5.0.1 and Angular v6.0.0

**Goal**

Pass an enum in a template-driven form using a radio-group.

**Try**

I tried the standard of Angular powered Bootstrap: [Lien vers Radio-group ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples)

```
 <span class="input-group-append" ngbRadioGroup name="periodePremierJour" [(ngModel)]="modelTest">
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="radio-inline">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="MATIN"> Matin
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="radio-inline">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="APRES_MIDI"> Après-midi
  </label>
</span>
<hr>
<pre>{{periodeEtatEnum[modelTest]}}</pre>
```

and in the ts:

```
 periodeEtatEnum: PeriodeEtatEnum;
 modelTest : PeriodeEtatEnum;
```

and in an enum.ts:

```
export enum PeriodeEtatEnum {
    MATIN = 'Matin',
    APRES_MIDI = 'Après-midi'
}
```

Problem: modelTest is set to undefined.

**Second Try**

```
<div *ngFor="let choice of keysPeriode">
  <input type="radio"
       [(ngModel)]="modelTest"
       [checked]="'MATIN'==choice"
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
       [value]="choice" />
{{periodeEtatEnum[choice]}}<br>
```

```
periodeEtatEnum = PeriodeEtatEnum;
keysPeriode = Object.keys(this.periodeEtatEnum).filter( e => typeof( e ) == "string" );
modelTest : PeriodeEtatEnum;

ngOnInit(){
    this.modelTest = PeriodeEtatEnum.MATIN;
}
```

Problem: modelTest has the correct value when selected. However, the checked option is not working! Could you help me please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I've done it as follows

Create your enum

```
export enum myEnum{
    Customer = 1,
    Store = 2
}
```

In your component, take the enum and generated the keys from it.

```
// declaration
enumKeys: any;
this.enumKeys = Object.keys(this.myEnum).filter(Number);
```

And then in your template

```
 <div class="form-check " *ngFor="let item of enumKeys">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" (change)="onChanged($event)" [value]="item"> {{ myEnum[item] }}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the point of filter(Number)? When I try this, enumKeys send me back an empty array.

Comment: And if I use: Object.keys(this.myEnum) it send me back an array of key values ["Customer", "Store"] but then if I want to iterate through enumKeys it send me back: 'typeof myEnum' cannot be used as an index type.

Comment: It took me a while to make my code work using this approach. In my case I had a `Gender` enum defined. My problem was with the attr myEnum, which I was initializint as `myEnum: Gender;`, while it should be `myEnum = Gender;`. Then the code understand myEnum as a representation of the Gender enum definition.